# To get comma separated value in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting data from Service in Controller as following

```
 public ActionResult UserAction(string username)
    {
        UserProfileModel userModel = SessionManager.GetValueOrDefault<string, UserProfileModel>("UserProfile");
        UserActionViewModel model = new UserActionViewModel();

        model.user = userModel.username;

        model.UserActionList = DataService.GetUserList(model.user );

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return this.PartialView("_UserAction", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.View(model);
        }

       // return this.PartialView("_UserActionGrid", model);
    }
```

In View, I have created _UserActionGrid and created column, 
one of the column is

```
grid.Column(columnName: "User", header: "User Name", canSort: false),
```

I am getting output as abc, xyz in User Column. since my query returns multiple users.
I want Output must contain xyz on newline below abc. like

```
abc
xyz
```

Please assist.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta - It is web grid.

Comment: show your view code to understand and what are the properties of "UserActionViewModel" ?.....